# Determining tan of angle between two planes

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, contest-math

Three poles of height x ,x+y and x+z are posted at the vertices A B and C of a triangular park of sides a b and c respectively.A plane sheet is mounted at the tops of the poles.If the plane of the sheet is inclined at an angle theta to the horizontal plane how to find tan theta

Given x,y,z, a,b,c angle A

---

Here there must be two planes but I'm not able to start the problem. Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: Find normal vector to the plane that the sheet is in. The normal vector to the park surface is $(0, 0, 1)$.

Comment: The answer is independent of $x$ $-$ you can pretend that the poles have heights $0,y,$ and $z$.

Comment: Use vectors and cross and dot multiplications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a coordinate frame with its origin at vertex $A$, and its $x$-axis extending along $AB$.  Then the coordinates of $A = (0, 0, 0)$ and $B = (c, 0, 0)$.  From $a,b,c$ we can compute angle $A = \cos^{-1} \dfrac{c^2 + b^2 - a^2}{2 b c } $ and then the coordinates of $C = (b \cos A, b \sin A, 0)$.

Let the tops of the poles attached to $A,B,C$ be $A', B', C'$ then

$A' = (0, 0, x) , B' = (c, 0, x + y) , C' = (b \cos A , b \sin A , x + z )$

The normal to the plane $A'B'C'$ is given by $n = A'B' \times A'C'$

hence,

$n = (c, 0, y) \times (b \cos A , b \sin A, z ) = (- y b \sin A , y b \cos A - c z, bc \sin A)$

The requested angle is the angle between the normal $n$ and the unit vector along the $z$-axis which is $\hat{k} =(0, 0, 1)$, hence

$\theta = \cos^{-1} \dfrac{n_z}{|n|} =  \cos^{-1} \dfrac{b c \sin A}{\sqrt{ y^2 b^2 + c^2 z^2 - 2 b c y z \cos A + b^2 c^2 \sin^2 A }}$